# How to use owl carousel WordPress plugin?

Tags: wordpress, owl-carousel

I didn't find enough resource to know about **owl carousel** WordPress plugin. If you know please explain.

Comment: show us what have you tried, as I remember they have a good documentation, so I think all you need is to read their docs

Answer (score 0):

I'd get the image URL and simply loop through the post instances inside a While loop (or THE loop) - essentially, the basic loop for getting post assets.

I'm using the toolset plugin and calling the elements where needed using said loop.

```
<ul class="attributes">
            <?php
                $values = array( 
                    // 'author_name' => 'author',
                    'post_type' => 'attribute',
                    'orderby' => 'id'
                );

                $query = new WP_Query( $values );

                if ( $query->have_posts() ) : 
                    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
                $name = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wpcf-value-name', true);
            ?>

            <li>
                <div class="values-content">
                    <div class="title">
                        <p><?php echo $name; ?></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text">
                        <p><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wpcf-value-text', true); ?></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="icon">
                        <?php $icons = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wpcf-value-icon', true); ?>
                        <img src="<?php echo $icons; ?>" alt="<?php echo $name; ?>">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>

            <?php endwhile; else: ?>
                <p>Sorry, there are no posts to display</p>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </ul>
```

If you need any help with this, let me know. If you decide to stick with the plugin, that's fine but I'm not acquainted with it :) I'm calling the 'attributes' class name in the jQuery:

```
// carousel for about page values   
jQuery(".attributes").owlCarousel({
    autoWidth: true,
    items: 1
});
```